# Why is project id attached to my Datastore Key object?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

For some inexplicable reason, my `project id` is attached to the Key of my `User` entity:

```
<Key('User', 5703358593630208), project=my-project-id>
```

This is giving me issues, such as when I am trying to use this same key as an ancestor of another entity — I would get this error:

```
google.cloud.ndb.exceptions.BadValueError: Expected Key instance, got <Key('User', 5703358593630208), project=my-project-id>
```

I created the `User` entity like this:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
datastore_client = datastore.Client()

def save_user(name):
    key = datastore_client.key('User')
    user = datastore.Entity(key=key)
    user.update({
        'name': name,
        'created': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    })
    datastore_client.put(user)
```

Additional Example: Making an ancestral query

```
query = MyEntity.query(ancestor=user_key)

TypeError: ancestor must be a Key; received <Key('User', 5752652897976320), project=my-project-id>
```

What could be the explanation for this?

Comment: The project is an expected part of a key object in the google-cloud-datastore library, https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/keys.html. Can you show an example of how you set the ancestor entity?

Comment: @JuanLara, I have included an additional example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are using both `google.cloud.datastore` and the `NDB` library and the key objects are not compatible. Here's an example of converting a datastore client key to an NDB key:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
from google.cloud import ndb

# Start with a google.cloud.datastore key
datastore_client = datastore.Client()
datastore_key = datastore_client.key('Parent', 'foo', 'User', 1234)


def key_to_ndb_key(key):
    # Use flat_path property to create an ndb_key
    key_path = key.flat_path
    ndb_key = ndb.Key(*key_path)
    return ndb_key


# Convert to a ndb key
ndb_client = ndb.Client()
with ndb_client.context() as context:
    ndb_key = key_to_ndb_key(datastore_key)
    print(ndb_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Entities are partitioned into subsets, currently identified by a project ID and namespace ID.

for more reference please [check google doc](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Key) and [this](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/datastore/latest/v1.DatastoreClient.html).